# How to patch linux kernel to add gyroscope support

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I'm trying to use MPU3000/3050 by Invensense with embedded linux (ARM-based LPC3141 board, Embedded Artists).
I found this interesting patch on the Internet

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/703991/

how can I implement it in my kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/) for detailed instructions on how to apply a patch.

Warning: kernel patches are quite often highly specific to the version of Linux they were developed for, so if your kernel version is different from the one the patch was originally made for you may encounter some problems.

Edit: I had a look at this particular patch and essentially it creates a new file (mpu3050.c) and modifies drivers/input/misc/Makefile and drivers/input/misc/Kconfig.  Even if everything else fails the new file should be created, and the mods to the existing files can probably be done manually.

Comment: So basically I can: (1) add the "+" text to Kconfig; (2) add the "+" line to Makefile; (3) create the new file "mpu3050.c" and it's done, right?

Comment: @stef yes, but that sort of manual surgery should be a plan b, should the patch command fail.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about the details, but you should download the kernel from www.kernel.org, patch it with the 'patch' utility and configure it to compile it. You should search some manuals for the configuration.

I am not sure if you already knew this, though.